# How to use reflection on a COM object exposed through the RCW?

Tags: c#, reflection, com

I used the Type Library Importer (TlbImp.exe) to generate an interop assembly for interfacing with a COM object. Something I am trying to do is build an expression tree that calls a method on a COM object. I want to compile the expression tree into a lambda and cache it.

The reason I want to do this is because in this COM object, there are many similar interfaces where the only thing that changes is the parameter type. For example, there is an interface for IFooDouble, IFooInt, IFooString, IFooLongInt, etc. Then each one will define a method SetValue(T value) where T will be either double, int, string, etc., depending on the interface. Here I would compile an expression tree into an `Action<IFooBase, T>` lambda and cache it.

The generated interop assembly contains strongly typed interfaces to the `SetValue` method, but I cannot find a way to get a reference to it's `MethodInfo` object through reflection. Since the wrapper type is `System.__ComObject`, I can call `InvokeMember` and do it that way. However,  I am wondering if it will be much slower than if I were to call the method directly through one of the interop interfaces? That is, I am wondering if `IFooBase.InvokeMember("SetValue", ...)` is going to have much worse performance over `IFooDouble.SetValue(11.3)`, especially when doing many repeated calls.

Comment: That doesn't match the question's title, but if the question is "is using an IDispatch interface slower than an IUnknown derived interface" (.NET put apart), the answer is yes. If you need intensive repeated calls, it's better to define an IUnknown-derived interface (also called vtable binding or "early binding" vs IDispatch being "late binding"). And also take care on how you define your methods and parameters (types, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work after doing some experimenting in a throw away console app. It turns out I made a few mistakes in the reflection calls. I didn't use the full type name of the interface, which includes the namespace, in the `Assembly.GetType` method. I also didn't specify the correct flags in the `BindingFlags` argument of `Type.GetMethod`.

Here is a working version of it:

```
private static Action<object, T> CreateSetterExpression<T>(string fooType)
{
    // IFoo is a base interface in the interop assembly that
    // we are interested in.
    var fooBaseInterfaceType = typeof(IFoo);
    var fooInterfaceType = fooBaseInterfaceType.Assembly
        .GetType(
            $"{fooBaseInterfaceType.Namespace}.IFoo{fooType}",
            true,
            true);

    var setValueMethodInfo = fooInterfaceType.GetMethod("SetRequestedValue",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        CallingConventions.Any,
        new[] { typeof(T) },
        null);

    ParameterExpression instanceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instanceObject");
    var instanceExp = Expression.Convert(instanceParam, fooInterfaceType);

    ParameterExpression valueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "value");

    var callExpression = Expression.Call(instanceExp, setValueMethodInfo, valueParam);

    return Expression.Lambda<Action<object, T>>(
            callExpression, instanceParam, valueParam)
        .Compile();
}
```